# Why am I getting the Fortran runtime error End of file when my input file is not over?

Tags: io, fortran

I was trying to write a basic **fortran programme to multiple three matrices input from a file** and print out the matrix obtained after the multiplication of the matrices but I'm getting the **runtime error "end of file"** in spite of the fact that the file to me seems to contain input in the the right form.

MY CODE::

```
program three_matmul
implicit none

integer,dimension(100,100) ::a,b,c,d,r
integer m,n,p,q
integer i,j,k,s,addn

open(unit=1,file="threematmul_inp.txt",status="unknown")
open(unit=2,file="threematmul_out.txt",status="unknown")

read (1,1001)m,n,p,q
1001 FORMAT(2X,I2,3X,I2,3X,I2,3X,I2)

do 5 i=1,m

    do 6 j=1,n

    read(1,1002)a(i,j)
    1002 format(2X,I2)

!   write(2,1003) a(i,j)
!   1003 format(X,I2)

    6 continue
5 continue

do 7 i=1,n

    do 8 j=1,p

    read(1,1004) b(i,j)
    1004 format(2X,I2)

!   write(2,1005) b(i,j)
!   1005 format(X,I2)

    8 continue
7 continue

do 9 i=1,p

    do 10 j=1,q

    read(1,1006)c(i,j)
    1006 format(2X,I2)

!   write(2,1007) c(i,j)
!    1007 format(X,I2)

    10 continue
9 continue

close(unit=1)

do 11 i=1,m
    do 12 k=1,p
        addn=0
        do 13 j=1,n

        13 addn = addn + a(i,j)*b(j,k)
        r(i,k) = addn

    12 continue
11 continue

do 19 i=1,m
    do 100  k=1,q
    addn =0.0

        do 111 j=1,p
        111 addn = addn + r(i,j)*c(j,k)

        d(i,k) = addn
    100 continue
19 continue

do 1250 i=1,m  
    do 1350 k=1,q

    write(2,1008) d(i,k)
    1008 format(2X,I2)

    1350 continue
1250 continue

close(unit=2)

endprogram three_matmul
```

INPUT FILE::

```
m=01 n=02 p=03 q=04

  01  01

  02  02  02
  03  03  03

  01  01  01  01
  02  02  02  02
  03  03  03  03
```

ERROR MESSAGE::

```
At line 44 of file three_matmul.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'threematmul_inp.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0x6f8aecb4
#1  0x6f8a11ce
#2  0x6f81fac4
#3  0x6f8a2ba7
#4  0x6f8ad597
#5  0x6f8ad815
#6  0x6f8c404f
#7  0x6f89b375
#8  0x401847
#9  0x401b92
#10  0x401287
```

Comment: Where is line 44?

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the reply. Line 44 is this one::    read(1,1006)c(i,j)                             Just above the statement   1006 .....

Comment: I recommend to add a debugging print after each write to see what was actually read. Or you can go through with a debugger.